# use css to repeat background image to certain position bottom

Tags: css

Not sure if there's an trick to do this but I am looking for a way to basically use CSS to repeat a background image(`repeat-y`) to a certain point at the bottom of the element like 80 px.

I really hope there an way to do this.

```
.rep-img {
    background-position: center left;
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    background-image: url('../images/image.png');   
    background-repeat-y-stop: 80px; /* made up property */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the background on a pseudo element:

```css
.rep-img {
    position: relative;
}

.rep-img:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('../images/image.png');
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; left: 0;
    bottom: 80px;
    z-index: -1; /* to push it behind any content in .rep-img */
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/T7JBx/

Comment: Actually you cannot, what if OP wants to again repeat that from 160px? he wants to do something like start at 0, end at 80, start from 150 again, now that's what I can make out from his made out property

Comment: @Mr.Alien - That can also be done. If the OP clarifies that that's what they want, I'll post some code.

Comment: Yes why didn't I think of this. Thank this works(in my example removed the z-index and replaced this with a width).

Comment: oh so he is happy with this so +1 :)